# Scroll function doesn't work properly with hyperlink

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a problem in my activity including scrollfunction together with a hyperlink. I have a button with information, and there is a scroll function added, cause it doesn't fit on the screen without that.

Now the scroll function works for a bit, but exactly on the point where I added the hyperlink, it stops. I added an image to show that, if you look at the image, imagine that I'm not able to scroll down any further than shown on the image, but there is still some information, including the hyperlink under that page. Which can't be shown this way.

[Click here to look at the image, it's scrolled down as far as i could, but not far enough yet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l813T.jpg)

If someone knows why I can't scroll down further to show the link and other information, any help would be appreciated.

This here is my main activity code for the page i'm having troubles with:

```
package com.example.rodekruis;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RouteActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{


     TextView HyperLink;
     Spanned Text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_route);

        findViewById(R.id.button11).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button12).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button13).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button14).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.imageButton1).setOnClickListener(this);

        TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        String text = getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_route);
        text += "<a href='https://www.google.nl/maps/place/Plein+1945+105,+1971+GC+IJmuiden/@52.4594977,4.6245747,18.5z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x47c5f0342468ea39:0xf05b19898f4b29!2sPlein+1945+105,+1971+GC+IJmuiden!3b1!8m2!3d52.4593706!4d4.6246212!3m4!1s0x47c5f0342468ea39:0xf05b19898f4b29!8m2!3d52.4593706!4d4.6246212'> Klik daarvoor op deze link</a>";
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {


        Intent intent = null;
        switch (v.getId()) {



            case R.id.button11:
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/RKZ.BrandwondencentrumBeverwijk");
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                break;
            case R.id.button12:
                Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/user/rodekruisziekenhuis/featured");
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri1);
                break;
            case R.id.button13:
                Uri uri2 = Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/rodekruiszh?lang=nl");
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri2);
                break;
            case R.id.button14:
                Uri uri3 = Uri.parse("https://www.linkedin.com/company/rode-kruis-ziekenhuis");
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri3);
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton1:
                intent = new Intent(RouteActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
                break;
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

this is the layout activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.Route" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:src="@drawable/informatiebutton" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ScrollView
         android:id="@+id/scrollview"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="364dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_route"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />


</ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Youtube" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Twitter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="LinkedIn" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the strings.xml where all the text is added, "route" is the one with the text in the page that I'm having troubles with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Rodekruis</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main"></string>
    <string name="title_activity_nieuws"><b>Nieuws</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Volg de ontwikkelingen in en om het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis op onze website, hier is een internetverbinding voor nodig. <a href='https://www.rkz.nl/nieuws_agenda_nieuws'> </a>
</string>
    <string name="title_activity_afspraak"><b>Afspraak</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<b>Maken en wijzigen</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Zelf uw afspraak maken of wijzigen? Dat kan, mits us al als patiënt geregistreerd staat bij het RKZ. Is dit nog niet het geval? Dan wordt de afspraak telefonisch gepland. Meer info&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<b>Bekijk ook</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\u2022 </string>  
    <string name="title_activity_bezoek"><b>Bezoektijden</b>\n\nVrijwel iedere patiënt vindt het prettig bezoek te ontvangen. Onze ervaring is
    dat een goed contact met vrienden en familie een bijdrage kan leveren aan 
    een spoedig herstel.\n\nVoor de meeste afdelingen gelden de volgende bezoektijden:\nvan 15.15 tot 16.15 uur;\nvan 19.00 tot 20.00 uur.\n\nLet op: tijdens feestdagen gelden in het RKZ andere bezoektijden dan normaal. Bekijk de website voor uitgebreide bezoektijden.
</string><string name="title_activity_contact">&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<b>Contact</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Telefoon en internet Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis&lt;br /&gt;T 0251 26 5555 (algemeen nummer, ook Poli IJmuiden)&lt;br /&gt;www.rkz.nl<a href="https://www.rkz.nl"> </a>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Huisartsenpost Midden-Kennemerland (begane grond RKZ)&lt;br /&gt;Voor huisartsenzorg buiten kantooruren&lt;br /&gt;T 0251 26 5265&lt;br /&gt;
    (A.u.b. bellen voordat u langskomt)&lt;br /&gt; Spoedeisende Hulp RKZ en Huisartsenpost: meer informatie&lt;br /&gt;Bij levensbedreigende klachten belt u altijd 112&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Bezoek- en postadres Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis&lt;br /&gt;Vondellaan 13&lt;br /&gt;1942 LE Beverwijk&lt;br /&gt;Route(link)&lt;br /&gt;Postbus 1074&lt;br /&gt;1940 EB Beverwijk
</string>
    <string name="title_activity_mening"><b>Uw mening</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Uw mening is voor het RKZ erg belangrijk. Graag horen we wat er goed gaat, wat beter kan en wat absoluut beter moet. Daarmee werken wij weer verder aan betere kwaliteit van zorg en patiëntenveiligheid.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;U kunt <br>uw mening</br> op verschillende manieren geven:&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;</string>
    <string name="title_activity_route">\n\n\n\n<b>Route</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis, hoofdgebouw&lt;br /&gt;Vondellaan 13&lt;br /&gt;1942 LE Beverwijk&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;De Velsertunnel is van medio mei tot eind 2016 gesloten.&lt;br /&gt;Voor verkeer vanuit zuidelijke richting is het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis in Beverwijk hierdoor moeilijker bereikbaar. Bekijk: &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\u2022    actuele verkeersinformatie korte routes naar/van het RKZ&lt;br /&gt;\u2022    actuele verkeersinformatie langere routers naar/van het RKZ&lt;br /&gt;\u2022    plan uw route naar/van het RKZ met      actuele verkeersinformatie&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;RKZ Poli IJmuiden (tijdelijk i.v.m. sluiting Velsertunnel)\nGezondheidscentrum Het Plein&lt;br /&gt;Plein 1945, nr.105&lt;br /&gt;IJmuiden&lt;br /&gt;\u2022    Plan uw route <a href='https://www.google.nl/maps/place/Plein+1945+105,+1971+GC+IJmuiden/@52.4594977,4.6245747,18.5z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x47c5f0342468ea39:0xf05b19898f4b29!2sPlein+1945+105,+1971+GC+IJmuiden!3b1!8m2!3d52.4593706!4d4.6246212!3m4!1s0x47c5f0342468ea39:0xf05b19898f4b29!8m2!3d52.4593706!4d4.6246212'> </a>&lt;br /&gt;\u2022    Meer informatie over de Poli IJmuiden</string>
    <string name="title_activity_specialisten"><b>Specialisten</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Op de website van het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis vindt u beknopte informatie over al onze specialisten. Om deze informatie te raadplegen heeft u een internetverbinding nodig. &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;U kunt in het specialistenoverzicht zoeken op achternaam of op specialisme. <a href='https://www.rkz.nl/specialisten_en_behandelaren/?group=rks'> </a></string>
    <string name="title_activity_bwc">  &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt; &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<b>Brandwondencentrum</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Het RKZ Brandwondencentrum, beter bekend als: Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk, levert al meer dan veertig jaar topklinische zorg op het gebied van huid-, brandwonden- en littekenbehandelingen en wordt zowel in het binnen- als buitenland hoog gewaardeerd.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Wie werken er in het Brandwondencentrum? Wat maakt het centrum zo bijzonder? Wat is een brandwond precies, wanneer is behandeling in het Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk nodig? Welke behandelingen vinden er plaats? Hoe vindt een opname plaats en wat zijn de bezoekregels? En welke afdelingen en poliklinieken behoren tot het brandwondencentrum?&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Op de website van Brandwondencentrum worden deze vragen uitegebreid beantwoord.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk heeft speciaal voor kinderen en tieners een <a href='https://www.rkz.nl/het_kinderbrandwondencentrum'> </a>
    </string>
    <string name="title_activity_agenda">AgendaActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_informatie">&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<b>Welkom op de RKZ app!</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;U heeft de app gedownload van het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis in Beverwijk. Met onze app geven wij u beknopte, praktische informatie over ons ziekenhuis die u deels offline (zonder internet) kunt raadplegen.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Voor vervolginformatie verwijzen wij u via links naar onze website. Hiervoor heeft u internet nodig.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Bent u in het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis, dan kunt u gebruik maken van gratis Wifi (draadloos internet). Hoe werkt het?&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\u2022   Ga naar de WiFi-instellingen op uw mobiele apparaat.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\u2022   Maak verbinding met het netwerk <b>RKZ_Bezoekers.</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\u2022    Open uw internetbrowser (zoals Internet, Explorer, Firefox of Safari)&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\u2022   U komt automatisch op de portal van het RKZ. Wilt u gebruik maken van Wifi in het RKZ, dan klikt u hier op <u>akkoord</u> om de voorwaarden te accepteren.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\u2022   De browser verwijst u door naar de pagina http://www.rkz.nl.</string>
    <string name="title_activity_vriend">\n\n\n\n<b>Word vriend van het RKZ</b>\n\nEen verblijf in het ziekenhuis is meestal niet erg plezierig. De Stichting Vrienden van het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis spant zich in om het verblijf van patiënten, bezoekers en medewerkers van het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis en het bijbehorende Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk te veraangenamen. Door geld in te zamelen voor voorzieningen die niet uit het basisbudget van het ziekenhuis kunnen worden betaald. Denk aan een opknapbeurt voor de speelkamer voor jonge patiënten of een verwenbehandeling bij een chemokuur.\n\nOok u kunt helpen. Door Vriend te worden van het RKZ of door ons eenmalig te steunen. Lees verder op de website.\n\nMet vrienden om je heen voel je je beter. Geef om het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis. 
    </string>
    <string name="title_activity_folders"><b>Folders</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Op de website van het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis kunt u folders downloaden over ziektebeelden, behandelingen en onderzoeken. Hiervoor heeft u een internetverbinding nodig.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;U kunt zoeken op trefwoord of op alfabet. <a href='https://www.rkz.nl/overzicht'> </a> 
</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a ScrollView

Set `TextView`

```
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

properties of your TextView in your layout's xml file.

Then use:

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

**Updated**

Your layout should like this (remove scrollview):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.Route" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:src="@drawable/informatiebutton" />
    </FrameLayout>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="364dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:scrollbars ="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_route"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Youtube" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Twitter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="LinkedIn" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And in activity (ScrollingMovementMethod link below):
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/ScrollingMovementMethod.html

```
TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: that android:scrollbars = vertical, where am i suppose to type that

Comment: It gives an error on ScrollingMovementMethod, it cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: You set `android:scrollbars = "vertical"` at `TextView` in your `ScrollView`

Comment: you can try `yourTextView.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());`

Comment: ScrollingMovementMethod cannot be resolved is still the error i get. the "your" in yourtextview, can be deleted i'm assuming? not an expert with this yet.

Comment: Did you remove Scrollview ? and why: ScrollingMovementMethod cannot be resolved? It 's in `android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod`.

Comment: No i did not remove scrollview. And where android.text.method.scrollingmovementmethod? Can't seem to find that. Above it says import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod, but when i add your line, or replace it with your line, it's still giving the error.